# syntaxhighlighter -- insert link to file instead of pasting snippet

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

Is there any way to insert a link to a file containing source code, instead of pasting the code directly into the webpage to achieve syntax highlighting?  (*With the "ability to place virtually anything inside the CDATA without having to escape anything . . ."*)

```
<pre class="brush: js">

/home/lawlist/archives/init.el

</pre>
```

Comment: @beautifulcoder resolved the issue in a related thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175287/how-to-include-a-file-and-wrap-its-contents-in-a-pre-tag?noredirect=1#comment35443414_23175287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@beautifulcoder resolved the issue in a related thread:  [How to include a file, and wrap its contents in a `pre` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175287/how-to-include-a-file-and-wrap-its-contents-in-a-pre-tag?noredirect=1#comment35443414_23175287)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  ajaxRq.open("GET", "/home/lawlist/archives/init.el", false);
  ajaxRq.send(null);
  document.write('<pre class="brush:  lisp">');
  document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
  document.write('</pre>');
</script>
```