# How to include a file, and wrap its contents in a `pre` tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for an example demonstrating how to insert *the contents of a file* and wrap *the contents* in a `pre` tag -- e.g., `<pre ...> insert.txt </pre>`.  The usage will be to insert code snippets.

The following is an example of how it would work, but this particular example does *not* work because the javascript code is treated as a code snippet.

```
<pre . . .>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  ajaxRq.open("GET", "license.txt", false);
  ajaxRq.send(null);
  document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
</script>

</pre>
```

Comment: Something like this may point you to the right direction: `document.getElementById('pre#license').innerText(ajaxRq.responseText);`

Comment: I'm on a shared server and am open to suggestions.  The solution does not need to use the sample code that I've provided in my question above.  I'd need to do some reading about `jquery` to know whether the answer is yes or no, sorry -- at this time, I do not know that answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Let me see if I understand you correctly: you need to load data from a file (which can be code) and need that placed in a desired pre tag without being processed?

Comment: @Anthony Calandra -- the `pre` tags is what makes the fancy highlighting for the code that will be inserted, and the code is contained in another file -- e.g., `insert.txt`.  In this short example, the file `insert.txt` will have a line of code that says: `Hello-world!`.  So, the whole thing needs to be processed as `<pre . . .>Hello-world!</pre>`

Comment: Thank you everyone -- @beautifulcoder hit the nail on the head -- I just replaced `document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);` with the answer and that fixed everything.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to simply add the `<pre>` tags through javascript:

```
document.write('<pre>');
document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
document.write('</pre>');
```

This isn’t my preferred way of doing things but it works. jQuery will just make you type up less code.

Comment: Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!  I just replaced the line of code `document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);` with your answer and it worked perfectly.  :)

Comment: This assumes your data is properly converted to HTML entities.

Comment: @Anthony Calandra -- I'm using Syntaxhighlighter by Alex Gorbatchev, which takes care of the conversion on newer browsers, but has limitations for some tablet readers and so forth.